# How can replace requestLegacyExternalStorage with something suitable for google console for copying user file?

Tags: android, exception, permissions

I'm trying to copy an image from user storage

```
File(userStorageImagePath).copyTo(userProfileImage, overwrite = true)
```

but then user chose the image the exception appears:

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)  /storage/emulated/0/Download/....
```

all access granted read/write and exception
appears only on android 10

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` solve issue,

but how can I replace requestLegacyExternalStorage to something suitable for google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
val inputStream: InputStream? = getMediaUriFromPath(ctx, userStorageImagePath)?.let { ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }
Files.copy(inputStream, imageDestinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)

fun getMediaUriFromPath(context: Context, path: String): Uri? {
        val mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            mediaUri,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?",
            arrayOf(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)),
            null
        )
        var uri: Uri? = null
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    mediaUri,
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID))
                )
            }
        }
        cursor?.close()
        return uri
    }
```